# visual studio code react-native: Current workspace is not a React Native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am struggling trying to setup a simple application with visual studio code and react-native. I have followed the getting started tutorial https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native. I have installed the required extensions into visual studio code (mainly react native tools). I have also setup various global variables (ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME). I am using genymotion as my emulator.

After having setup my environment, I create a react-native project using react-native-cli:

```
react-native init my_project
```

First of all, from Visual studio code, Debug page, I select React-Native as my debug environment. A launch.json file is generated. But I see that the file **launchReactNative.js** is not generated.

Second if I execute this command (within vs code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>):

```
React-native: run-android
```

I get this message "Current workspace is not a React Native project"

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have searche through google and stackoverflow but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Why is my workspace not recognized as a React-native project?

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "poxx",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "15.4.1",
        "react-native": "0.39.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
        "jest": "17.0.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}{
    "name": "poxx",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "15.4.1",
        "react-native": "0.39.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "17.0.2",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
        "jest": "17.0.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
[image: File structure]

**Edit 2: react-native package within node_modules**

[image]

Comment: In vs code, did you open your 'my_project' folder (File -> Open -> Select 'my_project' folder) before you execute Run Android within vs code?

Comment: After having created the project with "react-native init my_project", I opened it from the windows context menu: I right-clicked on the folder and selected the "open with code" option.

Comment: If I click the green run button (with "Debug Android" option selected) and try to run the project, in the Debug console, I get the error: 
[Error] "Could not debug. Unable to set up communication with VSCode react-native extension. Is this a react-native project, and have you made sure that the react-native npm package is installed at the root?"

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the Explorer (the one that shows the folder structure) of vs code? By the way, your package.json, is it copy/paste error cause I see there is a duplicate.

Comment: yes...sorry package.json seems to be a copy/paste error

Comment: I have just edited my question with a screenshot of the explorer

Comment: Sorry, not this one. I meant the Explorer inside vs code (https://code.visualstudio.com/images/codebasics_hero.png).

Comment: Here is the screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8jVZWU6DPKeMW1mVi11d1ZGVGc

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in `react-native-cli@2.0.0` and there is already a PR waiting to be merged. This should be fixed in the next release of `react-native-cli`. For now, the workaround is to revert to an earlier version, eg. `react-native-cli@.1.3.0`.

As suggested before, you can install it with `npm i -g react-native-cli@1.3.0`

More about the bug can be found here: [react-native/issues/11463](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11463) and here: [vscode-react-native/issues/365](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/365)

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the input. I will try it as soon as possible. Please could it also be possible you may give me a hint on another stack-overflow question I uploaded related to react-native ( specifically: 
React-native: How to use (and translate) typescript .tsx files with jsx in React-native?, you may have a lookup on it) Thank you.

Comment: This issue is still present in react-native-cli v2.9.0

Answer (score 1):

sometimes u need to eject ur project to be able to run it.
A typical react native project will have the following characteristics, in the order of how accurately it indicates that this is a react-native project.

React-native mentioned as a dependency in package.json
A react-native folder inside node_modules
An “android” and an “ios” folder at the top level
Usually an index.android.js and index.ios.js at top level

-----U shouldn't manually add these folders!!!!
follow these steps :

1-

`npm i -g react-native-cli`

## or

`yarn global add react-native-cli`

2- your app.json should be like :

```
{
"name": "AwesomeProject", //or whatever your project's name is


 "displayName": "AwesomeProject"
}
```

3- run `$ react-native eject`

Comment: I had deleted app.json since my hybrid RN app was not using it. Adding a dummy version back made VS Code happy. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to simulate the issue, it is due to react-native-cli v2.0.0.

Try uninstall it with `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`. Then, reinstall v1.0.0 with `npm install -g react-native-cli@1.0.0`.

Probably there is something wrong between v2.0.0 and react native tools extension in vs code.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try it as soon as I am back from office and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Bug caused by `react-native-cli 2.0.0`

fixed in `react-native-cli 2.0.1`

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.1 and I'm still getting this error.